# cut rows between 2 values and pasting it on a new sheet

Tags: excel, vba

I am new and I've been trying to work on this macro for a few days now. What I am trying to do is to search thru column A for the word "REPORT"; then cut and paste all rows in between "report" (including blanks rows) to a new sheet. It kinda works but it would not stop because it would continue to look for the "REPORT". Here's how my data looks like. Thanks.

**Table:**

```
         A
  ---------------
 1| REPORT
 2| SOLICITOR_ID
 3| ISSUER:
 4| CUSIP:
 5| RECORD_DATE:
 6| TOTAL
 7|
 8|
 9|
10|
11|
12| REPORT
13| SOLICITOR_ID
14| ISSUER:
15| CUSIP:
16| RECORD_DATE:
17|
18|
19|
20|
21|
22| REPORT
23| SOLICITOR_ID
24| ISSUER:
25| CUSIP:
26| RECORD_DATE:
27|
28|
```

**Code:**

```
Sub BRGFileCleanup()

Dim rownum As Long
Dim colnum As Long
Dim startrow As Long
Dim endrow As Long 
Dim lastrow As Long

Do
    rownum = 1
    colnum = 1
    lastrow = Worksheets("BRG_FILE").Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("BRG_FILE").Range("A1:A" & lastrow)

    For rownum = 1 To lastrow

Do
    If .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "REPORT" Then
       startrow = rownum

    End If

    rownum = rownum + 1

 If (rownum > lastrow) Then Exit For

 Loop Until .Cells(rownum, 1).Value = "REPORT"
    endrow = rownum - 1
    rownum = rownum + 1

    Worksheets("BRG_FILE").Range(startrow & ":" & endrow).Cut

    Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count)

    Range("A1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Paste
    Worksheets("BRG_FILE").Range(startrow & ":" & endrow).Delete

 Next rownum
 End With

Loop Until ActiveSheet.Range("A1").Value = ""

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

just be sure you have row 1 as a header row and then you can exploit `AutoFilter()` and `SpecialCells()` methods and `Areas()` property of `Range` object like follows:

```
Option Explicit

Sub main()
    Dim iArea As Long
    Dim filteredRng As Range

    With Worksheets("BRG_FILE")
        With .Range("A1", .Cells(.Rows.count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1))
            .Cells(.Rows.count) = "REPORT"
            .AutoFilter field:=1, Criteria1:="REPORT"
            If Application.WorksheetFunction.Subtotal(103, .Resize(, 1)) > 1 Then
                Set filteredRng = Intersect(.Parent.UsedRange, .Resize(.Rows.count - 1).Offset(1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).EntireRow)
            End If
            .Cells(.Rows.count).ClearContents
        End With
        .AutoFilterMode = False
    End With

    If Not filteredRng Is Nothing Then
        With filteredRng
            For iArea = 1 To .Areas.count - 1
                Sheets.Add After:=Sheets(Sheets.count)
                .Parent.Range(.Areas(iArea), .Areas(iArea + 1).Offset(-1)).Cut
                ActiveSheet.Paste
            Next
        End With
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: @Arvsden, did you get through it?